# displaying data from inner join

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

i need help displaying this in two different lists

```
$domains_sql = mysql_query("SELECT domains_id, domains_url, keywords_id, keywords_word, domains_comments_comment

     FROM
     (
     SELECT domains_id,domains_url
     FROM domains
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 1
     ) as d

     INNER JOIN domains_comments
     ON domains_comments_domain = domains_id

     INNER JOIN domains_keywords
     ON domains_keywords_website = domains_id

     INNER JOIN keywords
     ON domains_keywords_keyword = keywords_id
         ORDER BY keywords_word ASC") or die (mysql_error());


$num = mysql_num_rows($domains_sql);

$current_price = "";


for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){


$domains_result = mysql_fetch_array($domains_sql);

$domains_id = $domains_result['domains_id'];
$domains_url = $domains_result['domains_url'];
$domains_name = preg_replace('#^https?://www.#', '', $domains_url);                

$keywords_id = $domains_result['keywords_id'];
$keywords_word = $domains_result['keywords_word'];

$domains_comments = $domains_result['domains_comments_comment'];

if($domains_url != $current_price) {

echo $domains_name."<br /><br />";

$current_price = $domains_url;

}

echo $keywords_word."<br />";
echo $domains_comments."<br />";
}
```

prints out:

> MS Office
>   domain 1
>   MS Office
>   domain 1 - part 1
>   MySQL
>   domain 1
>   MySQL
>   domain 1 - part 1
>   PHP
>   domain 1
>   PHP
>   domain 1 - part 1
>   Visual Basic
>   domain 1
>   Visual Basic
>   domain 1 - part

and i need it to be:

(info from keywords)

> MS Office
>   MySQL
>   PHP
>   Visual Basic

(info from comments)

> domain 1
>   domain 1 - part 1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I see how your domain comments and keywords are related, and if you simply want two lists or if you want one comment-list per keyword.

Anyway, you could rewrite your query logic to make a primary query for the keywords, and then run simpler queries for the comments (either one for all, or one per keyword), but if your query time and dataset is such that you prefer doing it in a single query you can restructure the data in multiple-leve arrays.

Also, i presume you only want to list every item once.

```
$keywords = array();
$comments = array(); //if you want all comments in one list
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
  $domains_result = mysql_fetch_array($domains_sql);

  //Stores complete row data, only keeps the last, if the same value is fetched from the db several times
  $keywords [$domains_result['keywords_word']] = $domains_result;
  $comments[$domains_result['domains_comments_comment']] = $domains_result;
}
//Now you have the two list, could be printed several ways, to only print the values
print implode("<br />\n",array_keys($keywords));
print "<br />";
print implode("<br />\n",array_keys($comments));

//Loop trough
foreach ($keywords as $keyword=>$data) {
  print "$keyword<br>\n";
  print $data['keywords_word']."<br>\n";
  print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: thats you very much. this is perfect

Comment: Glad to hear @user1856414, if this really solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted, to remove your quesiton from the queue :)

Comment: with regards to the keywords part of this, i want to be able to display the keywords like <a href="'.$keywords_id.'">'.$keywords_word.'</a> can anybody help on this please?